# ¿ Cómo obtener datos de atributos de otras etiquetas?

Tags: javascript, html5

En el HTML he armado una estructura de una tarjeta:

```
<div class="item">
     <img class="trj_img_cls" src="<?php echo $cpui['path_foto'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $cpui['descripcion_producto'] ?>" id="<?php echo $cpui['descripcion_categoria'].','.$cpui['descripcion_subcategoria'].','.$cpui['descripcion_producto'].','.$cpui['precio'] ?>" onclick="javascript: clave()">
     <div class="nombre_producto">
          <h2 id="<?php echo $cpui['descripcion_categoria'].','.$cpui['descripcion_subcategoria'].','.$cpui['descripcion_producto'].','.$cpui['precio'] ?>" onclick="javascript: clave()"><?php echo $cpui['descripcion_producto'] ?></h2>
     </div>
          <div class="info-trj">
               <div class="precio-trj">
                    <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                    <label><?php echo $cpui['precio'] ?></label>
               </div>
               <i class="agrega-carro icon-cart-plus"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="caracteristicas">
               <ul id="<?php echo $cpui['descripcion_producto'] ?>"></ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

En la actualidad estoy consultando para poder elaborar una función en javascript que mediante el pseudo botón  que es el `<i>` obtenga algunos valores (nombre, el src de la imagen y el precio) sin tener que agregar nuevamente un atributo id en la respectiva etiqueta:

```
let allContainerCart = document.querySelector('.caja_contenido');

loadEventListeners();
function loadEventListeners() {
   allContainerCart.addEventListener('click',addProduct);
}

function addProduct(e) {}
```

; en la función `addProduct` quiero crear una variable que va a ser igual al div con clase="item", y de lo que he visto hasta el momento puedo acceder al padre del elemento mediante `e.target.parentElement` pero **¿Quisiera saber cómo puedo llegar hasta el div con
la clase item?** porque estoy utilizando `e.target.parentNode` y en consola obtengo object HTMLDivElement pero no se si es la correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) con el selector de clase '.item':

```
e.target.closest('.item')
```